# Error: couldn't find any revision to build- Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a problem with some Jenkins pipelines: When I trigger them with old commits, I receive the following error:

```
git rev-parse e14aea3d252fc61f29ee7f41e623a78e0e0e5e47^{commit} # timeout=10
git rev-parse origin/e14aea3d252fc61f29ee7f41e623a78e0e0e5e47^{commit} # timeout=10
git rev-parse e14aea3d252fc61f29ee7f41e623a78e0e0e5e47^{commit} # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
```

[image: screenshot:]

In the example above, the commit is 5 months old. The pipeline receives 3 parameters: the repository name, branch name and commit sha1. I use Bitbucket as the repository hosting service.

This problem doesn't occur with newer commits (when I trigger the pipeline with commits from two months ago or from a few days ago, it works fine. Therefore, I think that the problem is not with Jenkins configuration. In addition, I verified that "shallow clone" and "lightweight checkout" options are not marked.)

Jenkins Configuration:

[Configuration-part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yViEu.png)
[Configuration-part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evpQj.png)

Does anybody have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can you display the configuration of your Jenkins job ? especially the git part ?

Comment: one blind guess : if your job is configured to only do a sparse clone/fetch of your repository,  it may well have only the most recent commits, and not the older ones.

Comment: @LeGEC thanks for the suggestion but I don't use sparse clone/fetch. I have added the Jenkins configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This can occur due to two issues:

1. Branch name you have provided doesn't exists in the repo. Pls verify the branch name in the repo and give correct branch name.
2. Branch exists and there are no latest changes committed in branch. You can simply touch any file and push the changes, it will automatically trigger the job.